# How to keep textbox data when copying a form to another computer?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a form with two textboxes and two buttons, I want the data in the two text boxes to be saved when the computer shuts down or when the form containing the two textboxes is copied to another computer.

[Savedata1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ra0U2.jpg)

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub SaveButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click
        My.Settings.SaveTitle = TextBox1.Text
        My.Settings.SaveBody = TextBox2.Text
        MsgBox("Saved textbox data")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.SaveTitle
        TextBox2.Text = My.Settings.SaveBody
    End Sub

    Private Sub EndButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles EndButton.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

With the above code, I can only save data when the computer shuts down, but when copying the form to another computer the data in the textbox is not saved.
Can you show me how to keep textbox data when copying form to another computer?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: To transfer data from one computer to another either you would need to have a config/parameters file and transfer the file as well or you need to have a web server with maybe a SQL database where the information is saved.

Comment: Application settings are not stored in the EXE itself.  They are stored in an XML config file.  If you want saved settings to travel with an application then you must copy the config file too.  Note User-scoped settings are stored on a per-user basis, so there will be multiple config files with possibly different setting values if multiple users have logged into Windows and used your application.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestions, I solved my problem. I used XML config file to store data of textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting the data from the TextBoxes to be shared among all copies of the application? Like if you change the values on one computer, they update on the others?

Or, do you want the data to be persistent on an application copy instance? Like if I have a copy and change the values, the person I share the application with shares my values?

If you want the data to be consistent across all instances, use a webserver to store the values (either in a data store or as a simple XML file), and have each instance download the values on startup, or at regular intervals.

If the values are to be set by you, the developer, you could simply recompile the application with the new values and let the ClickOnce deployment system handle all the client updates for you.

If you want the values set on a copy per copy basis, you will have to include a file containing the values with the application, so each new user gets the application and the settings file as part of the package.

Comment: Mike, thank you very much, I solved my problem. I used XML config file to store data of textbox.